libusb returns two different values for device descriptor when use two different functions
I want to use libusb library to communicate with an HID device. I could implement many of its functions and it was ok. but when I want to get the device descriptor with libusb_get_device_descriptor() function and with libusb_get_descriptor() function, it shows me different values for some fields like Control Max Packet Size.
I've coded as following for two functions:
#include <stdio.h>
#include "libusb.h"

int main(void)
{
  libusb_device_handle* dev_handle;
  int init = libusb_init(NULL);
  dev_handle = libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid(NULL, 0x04d8, 0x01ff);
  libusb_claim_interface(dev_handle, 0);

  unsigned char buf[18];
  
  //first function
  libusb_get_descriptor(dev_handle, LIBUSB_DT_DEVICE, 0, buf, sizeof(buf));

  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(buf); i++)
  {
    printf("%d ", buf[i]);
  }

// output
//18 1 0 2 0 0 0 64 216 4 255 1 0 1 1 2 0 1
  
  printf("\n");
  
  //second function
  struct libusb_device_descriptor desc;
  libusb_get_device_descriptor(libusb_get_device(dev_handle), &desc);
  printf("%d ", desc.bMaxPacketSize0);


  libusb_release_interface(dev_handle, 0);
  libusb_close(dev_handle);
  libusb_exit(NULL);
  return 0;
}

If you run the above code, the returned value for CTRL_Max_Packet_Size from the first function is equal to 64 but for the second function is 8 that obviously the second one is correct. but Why does the first function return wrong value?
I have checked the first function for other descriptors like CONFIG_DESCRIPTOR and at this case also there are some incorrect values for some fields.
I'm using Windows 10 64 bit and I have compiled my code with both visual studio and mingw64. both return same incorrect value.

Are you sure you're looking at the correct index in the buf array? Can you please [edit] your question to copy-paste (as text) the actual output you get?

Oh, and you should really add some error checking for the functions you call. What does, for example, libusb_get_descriptor actually return?

@Some programmer dude
Yes, the index is correct and the actual output from the first function is:
18 1 0 2 0 0 0 64 216 4 255 1 0 1 1 2 0 1
it's 18 bytes and the 8th byte of device descriptor is packet size that is wrong value.
I've edited the question.

I found the solution. The problem was for the default installed driver in win10 that is hidUsb. I changed the driver to WinUsb using the Zadig software and now everything is ok.
